# How to use RAR or ZIP to rename replaced files when extracting

Tags: zip, extract, rename, rar, winrar

I wish to extract files using RAR or ZIP but I need to be able to rename the files being replaced so that there is a copy of the previous version in case something goes wrong.

Couldn't see any options in WinRAR to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRAR will allow you to rename a file during extraction. Make sure you have 'Ask Before Overwrite' enabled and you will get a prompt:

[image]

Comment: Does this rename the original file or the new file?

Comment: It will keep the original and rename the file you are trying to extract. Of all the compression utilities I tried, I believe it was only WinRar and 7-zip, which I use, that even offered to rename files and they both work the same way. The only other option would be a command line script that renames the file then extracts the archive...

Comment: I need something that renames the original file.